# How exactly should I interpret the term "Hybrid Cloud"?

Tags: cloud-computing

The CISSP CBK definition says that a hybrid could is a mix of public and private.
But what exactly does it mean?

- Is it more a conceptual idea:If you use both a public and a private your company is a hybrid user

or

- You have a single cloud with different logical access and permissions for public usage and private (within the company)

or

Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at it from a service perspective instead of from a "cloud" perspective (there is no such thing as a "cloud").

If a service resides partially on a privately held network as well as on a publicly held network, then it's a "hybrid".

For example, I use a security service where I deploy multiple servers within my own network (private "cloud") and the data from those collectors is sent to the vendor's network (public "cloud") for processing and correlation. That's a "hybrid cloud".